# How to disable some of Win 10 Magnifier's shortcuts?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, magnifier

On Win 10, there is a built-in Magnifier. You can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in or out. Howerver, there are also some other shortcuts:

[image]

I want to know, how can I disable the three shortcuts in the screenshot and keep the zoom in & out shortcuts?

Comment: Yes. I haven't tried that and not sure if it's possible. Do you have any guide on this? Anyway, thanks for pointing out this and I'll take a look for sure.

Comment: I searched the Internet but there is no official way to disable the shortcut keys. All registry key or GPO are used for disable Win+other key. So we need to use third party tool to achieve this gool.